# SQLAlchemy get secondary table from relationship

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have the following three tables with irrelevant fields removed:

```
class Users(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)

    project_memberships = db.relationship("ProjectMember", back_populates = "user")

    def get_managed_projects(self):
        return [x.project for x in self.project_memberships if x.is_manager]


class Project(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "project"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    members = db.relationship("ProjectMember", back_populates = "project")


class ProjectMember(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "project_member"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"), nullable = False)
    user = db.relationship("Users", back_populates = "project_memberships")
    project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("project.id"), nullable = False)
    project = db.relationship("Project", back_populates = "members")
    is_manager = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable = False, default = False)
```

How can I write `get_managed_projects` using SQLAlchemy methods? I could use

```
db.session.query(Project).join(ProjectMember).filter_by(user = self, is_manager = True).all()
```

but is it possible to make use of `project_memberships` instead of using `user = self`?

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Comment: What do you mean? The query given works, I would like to know if it can be written using `self.project_memberships` instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved using the `secondary` and `secondaryjoin` relationship attributes. The relationships are `viewonly` so, like the functions, are read-only.

```
class Users(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)

    managed_projects = db.relationship("Project", secondary = "project_member",
        secondaryjoin = "and_(ProjectMember.project_id == Project.id, ProjectMember.is_manager == True)",
        viewonly = True, back_populates = "managers")

class Project(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "project"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    
    managers = db.relationship("Users", secondary = "project_member",
        secondaryjoin = "and_(ProjectMember.user_id == Users.id, ProjectMember.is_manager == True)",
        viewonly = True, back_populates = "managed_projects") 

class ProjectMember(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = "project_member"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("users.id"), nullable = False)
    user = db.relationship("Users", backref = "memberships")
    project_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey("project.id"), nullable = False)
    project = db.relationship("Project", backref = "memberships")
    is_manager = db.Column(db.Boolean, nullable = False, default = False)
```

Now `managed_projects` returns a list of `Projects` and `managers` a list of `Users`, bypassing the intermediate `ProjectMember`. `ProjectMember` objects can still be accessed using the `memberships` attributes on both `Users` and `Project`.

The code can be simplified by replacing `back_populates = "managers"` with `backref = "managers"` and removing `managers = ...` from `Project` but I thought that was less readable.